# Text around circle with Javascript

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg

I have searched around Stackoverflow for the same question, but all questions that looks a little bit like my question are programmed in Xcode (iPhone). I'm using Javascript, but I can't figure it out how I solve this.

I created a star (based on RaphaelJS). That star has a variable star points, so it could be a star with 8 points, but also 9 or 10 or 11.. My question is, I want text in a circle around that star. If the star has 8 points, then has every point it own word (so 8 words).

I have my problem illustrated in Illustrator, so maybe that my question clarified:

[image]

On this moment I'm doing it with images, but that isn't flexible (in the future I would generate the star and the words by using a database). I have searched a lot. I found that any technic where this is possible, is SVG. But after many hours of trial and error, I haven't something that is similar as my image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061880/html5-canvas-circle-text may contain some hints...

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Yes, but I can't use Canvas (HTML5), because Internet Explorer 7 and 8 don't support that.

Comment: For IE you can you excanvas.js library which brings canvas support to it.

Comment: I know excanvas.js, but it doesn't work for me. So I created the whole application with RaphaelJS (framework based on SVG) and now the application works on every browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create this shape in SVG. Use `polygon` to create the star and `text` and `textPath` to create the text surrounding the star.

See [this website](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp) for SVG examples. In particular you'll want to have a look at:

- [a star using polygon](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_polygon3),
- [text on a path](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_text3).

I also recommend to have a look at the relevant sections of [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/).

Comment: Thx, but I created the star with RaphaelJS already (based on SVG). So the only thing to solve this is using SVG? But could I positioning the words with SVG? Creating a long string with whitespaces isn't flexible, I think. And how should this technic work when the star has 12 points (so 12 words?).

Comment: You can draw the text and star on a canvas, too, but it may take more effort. The question was about the most flexible way of doing it since in the future the text and shape info would come from a db. SVG is the most flexible solution that allows for easy replacement of text and coordinates with practically no extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Ok admittedly I forgot where the points were in the image as this was the last thing I added (d'oh), but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7rrhX/) is what I knocked up using pure css, basically the idea is that you have all the text absolutely positioned in the centre of a div to start and then individually move them out from there. I think it would be quite simple to expand this idea with some js and cunning math.