# How Can I draw a Text Along arc path with HTML 5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a canvas graphic like this flash animation:
 http://www.cci.com.tr/tr/bizi-taniyin/tarihcemiz/

I drew six arcs and I want to write six words in these arcs. Any ideas?

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: You need to learn programming and mathematics. There is no easy "draw this text along this path" for HTML5 Canvas Context.

Comment: I am also a computer engineer and I know mathematics bro.

Comment: @phrogz I'm sure that Firefox used to support text along a path. ISTR, years ago, seeing a demo of text going around a circle using this feature, I also STR seeing a W3C canvas reference (for a future version I think) that allows a path to be given to the fillText() function - so maybe that's the same thing. It might just be a fantasy though.

Answer (score 27):

I have a jsFiddle to apply text to any arbitrary Bezier curve definition.  Enjoy http://jsfiddle.net/Makallus/hyyvpp8g/

```js
var first = true;
startIt();


function startIt() {
  canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
  canvasDiv.innerHTML = '<canvas id="layer0" width="300" height="300"></canvas>'; //for IE
  canvas = document.getElementById('layer0');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = "18px arial black";
  curve = document.getElementById('curve');
  curveText = document.getElementById('text');
  $(curve).keyup(function(e) {
    changeCurve();
  });
  $(curveText).keyup(function(e) {
    changeCurve();
  });




  if (first) {
    changeCurve();
    first = false;
  }

}

function changeCurve() {
  points = curve.value.split(',');
  if (points.length == 8) drawStack();

}

function drawStack() {
  Ribbon = {
    maxChar: 50,
    startX: points[0],
    startY: points[1],
    control1X: points[2],
    control1Y: points[3],
    control2X: points[4],
    control2Y: points[5],
    endX: points[6],
    endY: points[7]
  };

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(Ribbon.startX, Ribbon.startY);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(Ribbon.control1X, Ribbon.control1Y,
    Ribbon.control2X, Ribbon.control2Y,
    Ribbon.endX, Ribbon.endY);

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  FillRibbon(curveText.value, Ribbon);
}

function FillRibbon(text, Ribbon) {

  var textCurve = [];
  var ribbon = text.substring(0, Ribbon.maxChar);
  var curveSample = 1000;


  xDist = 0;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < curveSample; i++) {
    a = new bezier2(i / curveSample, Ribbon.startX, Ribbon.startY, Ribbon.control1X, Ribbon.control1Y, Ribbon.control2X, Ribbon.control2Y, Ribbon.endX, Ribbon.endY);
    b = new bezier2((i + 1) / curveSample, Ribbon.startX, Ribbon.startY, Ribbon.control1X, Ribbon.control1Y, Ribbon.control2X, Ribbon.control2Y, Ribbon.endX, Ribbon.endY);
    c = new bezier(a, b);
    textCurve.push({
      bezier: a,
      curve: c.curve
    });
  }

  letterPadding = ctx.measureText(" ").width / 4;
  w = ribbon.length;
  ww = Math.round(ctx.measureText(ribbon).width);


  totalPadding = (w - 1) * letterPadding;
  totalLength = ww + totalPadding;
  p = 0;

  cDist = textCurve[curveSample - 1].curve.cDist;

  z = (cDist / 2) - (totalLength / 2);

  for (i = 0; i < curveSample; i++) {
    if (textCurve[i].curve.cDist >= z) {
      p = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(textCurve[p].bezier.point.x, textCurve[p].bezier.point.y);
    ctx.rotate(textCurve[p].curve.rad);
    ctx.fillText(ribbon[i], 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();

    x1 = ctx.measureText(ribbon[i]).width + letterPadding;
    x2 = 0;
    for (j = p; j < curveSample; j++) {
      x2 = x2 + textCurve[j].curve.dist;
      if (x2 >= x1) {
        p = j;
        break;
      }
    }




  }
} //end FillRibon

function bezier(b1, b2) {
  //Final stage which takes p, p+1 and calculates the rotation, distance on the path and accumulates the total distance
  this.rad = Math.atan(b1.point.mY / b1.point.mX);
  this.b2 = b2;
  this.b1 = b1;
  dx = (b2.x - b1.x);
  dx2 = (b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x);
  this.dist = Math.sqrt(((b2.x - b1.x) * (b2.x - b1.x)) + ((b2.y - b1.y) * (b2.y - b1.y)));
  xDist = xDist + this.dist;
  this.curve = {
    rad: this.rad,
    dist: this.dist,
    cDist: xDist
  };
}

function bezierT(t, startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY) {
  //calculates the tangent line to a point in the curve; later used to calculate the degrees of rotation at this point.
  this.mx = (3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (control1X - startX)) + ((6 * (1 - t) * t) * (control2X - control1X)) + (3 * t * t * (endX - control2X));
  this.my = (3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (control1Y - startY)) + ((6 * (1 - t) * t) * (control2Y - control1Y)) + (3 * t * t * (endY - control2Y));
}

function bezier2(t, startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY) {
  //Quadratic bezier curve plotter
  this.Bezier1 = new bezier1(t, startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y);
  this.Bezier2 = new bezier1(t, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY);
  this.x = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.x) + (t * this.Bezier2.x);
  this.y = ((1 - t) * this.Bezier1.y) + (t * this.Bezier2.y);
  this.slope = new bezierT(t, startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, endY);

  this.point = {
    t: t,
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y,
    mX: this.slope.mx,
    mY: this.slope.my
  };
}

function bezier1(t, startX, startY, control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y) {
  //linear bezier curve plotter; used recursivly in the quadratic bezier curve calculation
  this.x = ((1 - t) * (1 - t) * startX) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1X) + (t * t * control2X);
  this.y = ((1 - t) * (1 - t) * startY) + (2 * (1 - t) * t * control1Y) + (t * t * control2Y);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <TR>
    <TH>Bezier Curve</TH>
    <TD>
      <input size="80" type="text" id="curve" name="curve" value="99.2,177.2,130.02,60.0,300.5,276.2,300.7,176.2">
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH>Text</TH>
    <TD>
      <input size="80" type="text" id="text" name="text" value="testing 1234567890">
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD colspan=2>
      <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Comment: You are a genious! awesome code, it was very usefull for me

Comment: Just to be clear, @Makallus, does this code only work for bezier curves with 2 anchor points and 2 control points?

Comment: How can I fit text inside path depend on text length. In this image, i try change curveSample number to example, https://3.pik.vn/2020cd3be257-91b2-4235-8ebf-f877f43a2417.png

Comment: This does not work for complex texts like Arabic. the letters don't stick together. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 14):

An old old question... nevertheless, on my blog, I take a fairly close look at creating circular text using HTML5 Canvas:

[html5graphics.blogspot.com](http://html5graphics.blogspot.com)

In the example, options include rounded text alignment (left, center and right) from a given angle, inward and outward facing text, kerning (adjustable gap between characters) and text inside or outside the radius.

There is also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbdszxjv/) with a working example.

It is as follows:

```
document.body.appendChild(getCircularText("ROUNDED TEXT LOOKS BEST IN CAPS!", 250, 0, "center", true, true, "Arial", "18pt", 0));

function getCircularText(text, diameter, startAngle, align, textInside, inwardFacing, fName, fSize, kerning) {
    // text:         The text to be displayed in circular fashion
    // diameter:     The diameter of the circle around which the text will
    //               be displayed (inside or outside)
    // startAngle:   In degrees, Where the text will be shown. 0 degrees
    //               if the top of the circle
    // align:        Positions text to left right or center of startAngle
    // textInside:   true to show inside the diameter. False draws outside
    // inwardFacing: true for base of text facing inward. false for outward
    // fName:        name of font family. Make sure it is loaded
    // fSize:        size of font family. Don't forget to include units
    // kearning:     0 for normal gap between letters. positive or
    //               negative number to expand/compact gap in pixels
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // declare and intialize canvas, reference, and useful variables
    align = align.toLowerCase();
    var mainCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctxRef = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var clockwise = align == "right" ? 1 : -1; // draw clockwise for aligned right. Else Anticlockwise
    startAngle = startAngle * (Math.PI / 180); // convert to radians

    // calculate height of the font. Many ways to do this
    // you can replace with your own!
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = '-10000px';
    div.style.left = '-10000px';
    div.style.fontFamily = fName;
    div.style.fontSize = fSize;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var textHeight = div.offsetHeight;
    document.body.removeChild(div);

    // in cases where we are drawing outside diameter,
    // expand diameter to handle it
    if (!textInside) diameter += textHeight * 2;

    mainCanvas.width = diameter;
    mainCanvas.height = diameter;
    // omit next line for transparent background
    mainCanvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgray'; 
    ctxRef.font = fSize + ' ' + fName;

    // Reverse letter order for align Left inward, align right outward 
    // and align center inward.
    if (((["left", "center"].indexOf(align) > -1) && inwardFacing) || (align == "right" && !inwardFacing)) text = text.split("").reverse().join(""); 

    // Setup letters and positioning
    ctxRef.translate(diameter / 2, diameter / 2); // Move to center
    startAngle += (Math.PI * !inwardFacing); // Rotate 180 if outward
    ctxRef.textBaseline = 'middle'; // Ensure we draw in exact center
    ctxRef.textAlign = 'center'; // Ensure we draw in exact center

    // rotate 50% of total angle for center alignment
    if (align == "center") {
        for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
            var charWid = ctxRef.measureText(text[j]).width;
            startAngle += ((charWid + (j == text.length-1 ? 0 : kerning)) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) / 2 * -clockwise;
        }
    }

    // Phew... now rotate into final start position
    ctxRef.rotate(startAngle);

    // Now for the fun bit: draw, rotate, and repeat
    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
        var charWid = ctxRef.measureText(text[j]).width; // half letter

        ctxRef.rotate((charWid/2) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight) * clockwise);  // rotate half letter

        // draw char at "top" if inward facing or "bottom" if outward
        ctxRef.fillText(text[j], 0, (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2));

        ctxRef.rotate((charWid/2 + kerning) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight) * clockwise); // rotate half letter
    }

    // Return it
    return (mainCanvas);
}
```

Comment: any idea why an < at the start of the text input would break the positioning until an > followed by some text is provided? 

To test:
- set the text to "<a" (breaks)
- then set the text to "<a>" (breaks)
- then set the text to "<a>a" (works)

Is the inner-working on the canvas element thinking that is a tag?

Comment: .. ahhhhh it is breaking on the "text height" calculation as it is detecting "html".  Update  div.innerHTML = text; to be div.innerHTML = $('<div>').text(text).html(); ... (assuming you are using jQuery)

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following code to see how to write text along an Arc Path using HTML5 Canvas

```js
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
  var len = str.length,
    s;
  context.save();
  context.translate(centerX, centerY);
  context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
  context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);
  for (var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    context.rotate(angle / len);
    context.save();
    context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
    s = str[n];
    context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
  context.restore();
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  centerX = canvas.width / 2,
  centerY = canvas.height - 30,
  angle = Math.PI * 0.8,
  radius = 150;

context.font = '30pt Calibri';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.lineWidth = 4;
drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Text along arc path', centerX, centerY, radius, angle);

// draw circle underneath text
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't in any built in way. Please note that SVG natively does support text along paths, so you might want to consider SVG instead!

But you can write custom code in order to achieve the same effect, as some of us did for this question here: [HTML5 Canvas Circle Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061880/html5-canvas-circle-text/6062195#6062195)