# How can i draw text on quadraticCurveTo using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wanted to draw text on curve created using quadraticCurveTo in canvas and curve can be change by using mouse, i found some of answer but those are about bezierCurveTo here is link 
[How Can I draw a Text Along arc path with HTML 5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974364/how-can-i-draw-a-text-along-arc-path-with-html-5-canvas).

so how can i draw text along with quadraticCurveTo ?

Comment: See [Documentation: Text on curve, cubic and quadratic beziers](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5235/text/19302/text-on-curve-cubic-and-quadratic-beziers#t=20160922113401050239)

Comment: Thanks markE, documentation is very helpful.