# How to smear svg along path in canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have a SVG that I would like to smear across a path that the user draws in canvas. Example of the effect I want to acheive:

[image]

I'm using paper.js (open to alternatives) and I've gotten as far as creating a line when the user drags their mouse and placing the svg (unwarped) at the end of that line. [Working sample of this code here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).

Comment: This is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974364/how-can-i-draw-a-text-along-arc-path-with-html-5-canvas