# How to draw an ovel shaped text in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a html5-canvas application which can draw line, circular text and now i need to write the text in oval shape.

[Click here to view the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBYXc.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw an oval in html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: text in oval shap, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited question for you to view the result i want.

Comment: Take a look at these questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061880/html5-canvas-circle-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974364/how-can-i-draw-a-text-along-arc-path-with-html-5-canvas)

Comment: All the above algorithm gives me the rounded shaped text.

Comment: Is there any other solutions.